# Fan error when booting in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, thinkpad, fan

Everything went normally, when yesterday night I was turning off my Thinkpad laptop. I did nothing special.

Today, when I tried to start using it, all I get is an error message "Fan error" and computer turns off. So, after boot screen, just "Fan error" and that's it.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you get a screen-shot?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a ubuntu related problem. Your fans are normally controlled by your bios. I would check if your fans are connected properly to your mainboard. Or just take him to the repair shop.